# EF 5.0 Code First Winforms Combobox Data Binding

Tags: entity-framework, data-binding

I'm trying to bind some lookup tables to comboboxes on winforms.  I've built the POCCO classes and generated the database.  I've added the data source to my app.  I drop the source tables onto the comboboxes in the designer and the binding gets set up fine for each.  I've populated the tables in the db with test data.

Here's where I need help.  With datasets I would simply do a tableadapter fill on the form Load event to get the data.  With EF I must have to do something to load the data.  Perhaps a query?  Something else? I bleieve everything is set up correctly.  Just need the final step to get it to load and work.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways how to communicate with your database. I understood, you are probably using EF Code First approach. Imagine this context:

```
public class WinFormContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Car> Cars { get; set; }
}

public class Car
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You are gonna add some record first. You create simple form with textboxs and one button.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (var WinFormContext = new WinFormContext())
        {
            Car car = new Car { Name = textBox1.Text };
            WinFormContext.Cars.Add(car);
            WinFormContext.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

It is simple solution, how to add new record after onClick event. Now you want to show all record in Grid View. One of the possible solution is fill the controll manually:

```
    BindingSource bindingSource = new BindingSource();
    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var WinFormContext = new WinFormContext();
        bindingSource.DataSource = WinFormContext.Cars.ToList();

        dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource;
        dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
    }
```

But there is more ways how to do it. I recommend you take a look on "data binding in win forms" on Google...

Comment: Please re-read the question.  I have obviously done everything you say already.  Except that I set up the binding in the VS designer rather than in code.  When I run the app the comboboxes don't fill.  I'm trying to figure out why.